# How can I use boost::test with xcode 4 for testing some ios c++ code?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, boost, xcode4

I would like it to operate similarly to how the normal test framework works - if you the tests  from the Product->Run tests menu item, the output should appear in the left sidebar window.

I found a [guide for using xcode 3 with boost test](http://richarddingwall.name/2008/06/01/using-the-boost-unit-test-framework-with-xcode-3/), but couldn't figure out how to translate those instructions for xcode 4 (if it is even possible).

Finally, I'm building an iPhone application. I could get boost running using the `#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>`, however it is pretty slow. Using the standard `#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>` results in link errors due to the library being built for the wrong architecture.

Comment: Old question, but I'm struggling with this too. Just pointing out that a solution is very much appreciated. Did you yourself perhaps find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I stopped working on the project I was going to use it for a while ago now as well, so I can't help you at all :(

Comment: You should build the boost library for ARM and x86 and then use lipo (man lipo) to merge them into one .a, that should fix the link errors about the library being built for the wrong arch etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the boost library to a static library ".a" using .configure and make.
According to [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/compilation/standalone.html):

> No special build options or macro definitions are required to build
>   the static library. Using the Boost.Build system you can build the
>   static library with the following command from libs/test/build
>   directory:
>
> bjam [-sTOOLS=] {-sBUILD=boost_unit_test_framework}

This library or libraries and their respective headers need to be added to the project. (Two built versions are needed, one i386 for the simulator and one ARM for devices).

- The static library is imported from `Link Binary with Libraries` in
  Build Phases.
- Also you need to tell XCode which of these to use, you
  can do this by setting contidional build settings in `Build settings-
- Library search paths. Above this line is where you add the `Header
  Search Path` to the boost header files.

After this you should be able to include the headers (Added above) in C++ or objective-C++ code of yours. (To make Obj-C files Obj-C++ files you need to change all deppendent `.m` files to `.mm`)

If there is a some problems after this, switching Compiler or standard library for C++ in Build Settings might help.