# Can boost test framework be run on IOS?

Tags: c++, ios, macos, unit-testing, boost

I have been using BOOST Test Library to perform unit test on different platforms such as Windows, Linux and MAC. But on IOS, if I still use the same unit test suite that have been used on Windows, Linux and MAC, it will fail. If I understand well about IOS, it is impossible to build an executable command line program that can run on IOS. While the unit test program that can run on Windows, Linux and MAC is a command line program. Moreover, the way how IOS handles the path is very different. I understand on IOS, people often xctest to perform the testing. I just wondering whether it is still possible to use BOOST Test library for unit test on IOS with xcode 4. Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8482524/how-can-i-use-boosttest-with-xcode-4-for-testing-some-ios-c-code)

Comment: `to build an executable command line program that can run on IOS` why not? you can. Just note that the only things you can see is an output log in xcode. Also note that ios has a strange behaviour when you program exit with code 0 (see [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605916/iphone-unexpected-duplication-of-tcp-packets-on-different-ports)).

Comment: I've experimenting with gtest and create a function that will add a test that will start [ios simulator](https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim) and parse it's output: [example](https://github.com/ruslo/sugar/blob/master/examples/04-gtest-universal/CMakeLists.txt). I thinks something similar can be done this boost.test